# Border radius in IE is not working

Tags: internet-explorer, rounding, css

I need to make round corners, when i am trying like this its working in firefox and chrome but not in IE.

```
#tab_labels div {
   border-top-right-radius:4px;
   border-top-left-radius:4px;
   -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
}
```

Comment: I got a quick question. Today I actually first learned about this `border-radius` and put it, it works perfect with my Firefox (8.0). What is the need for `-moz-border-radius*` then? Is it for older versions of Firefox?

Comment: Also, look [here](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/) If you can see round borders in IE, it means it works and you can check out the style sheet to see how they have done it

Comment: which version of IE is not support because IE8 & below are not support css3 properties

Comment: @Shahbaz the `-moz` prefix is used when support is still being developed, is in testing, or if the spec might change.

Comment: Isn't `-moz` prefix also used for some older versions of Firefox?

Comment: @motoxer4533 Yes. Older versions of Firefox will include that usually because of one of the above reasons. Also, one I forgot to note is if it is a browser extension that is not in the standards. Microsoft has a lot of these with it's `-ms` prefix. Well, starting in IE 8 their extensions now use the `-ms` prefix (like `-ms-filter`).

Answer (score 6):

Currently, IE 9 and 10 are the only versions of IE that support border-radius. IE 8 and below do not support border-radius. You'll need some 3rd party help, like [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/), to do that.

Comment: what does CSS3Pie?? What will it do?

Comment: From the site linked in my answer: PIE stands for Progressive Internet Explorer. It is an IE attached behavior which, when applied to an element, allows IE to recognize and display a number of CSS3 properties.

Comment: IE 8 and below does not. IE 9 supports `border-radius`

Comment: The OP didn't specify which version of IE they are using. Since the border-radius attribute didn't work from their code sample, it's safe to assume they're not using IE 9 or 10.

Comment: @motoxer4533 yes, likely. But it might be something you want to note. Add it and I'll upvote :)

Comment: @motoxer4533 I have PIE and testing in IE. Normally, the border-radius works fine but when I try to clone() it, the border-radius doesn't clone. Any ideas?

Comment: @triplethreat77 - have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455712/how-to-properly-clone-jquery-an-element-that-has-style-applied-through-pie  and  http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=914

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to start using CSS3.

You should really know that IE sucks.

Actually not only for CSS3. Just generally IE sucks.

So IE (up to 9) doesn't support rounded corners by default.

You should either use images / resort to some 3rd party stuff.

Answer (score 1):

border-radius will work in IE9, only not in versions below that (IE8, IE7, ...)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below meta tag to activate some CSS properties in IE. i use this tag and have no such problems.

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [PIE](http://css3pie.com/)

Example:

```
#yourdiv{
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

Comment: You have to download piecss3 package and then use its PIE.htc as behavior of your css rule.